# Image sorting in an array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

This is a simulation. How do I store this image into an array and sort in terms of most recent and most like.

Do i need to set up an id. Any help is appreciated.

```html
</style>


  
  <figure class="einzel"><img alt="Mitglieder" src="https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=0" style="width: 315px; height: 250px;">
    <figcaption>Name:<br>
      <span>Likes:</span></figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="einzel"><img alt="Mitglieder" src="https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=1" style="width: 315px; height: 250px;">
    <figcaption>Name:<br>
      <span>Likes:</span></figcaption>
      
  </figure>

  <figure class="einzel"><img alt="Mitglieder" src="https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=2" style="width: 315px; height: 250px;">
    <figcaption>Name:<br>
      <span>Likes:</span></figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="einzel"><img alt="Mitglieder" src="https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=3" style="width: 315px; height: 250px;">
    <figcaption>Name:<br>
      <span>Likes:</span></figcaption>
  </figure>
  
    <figure class="einzel"><img alt="Mitglieder" src="https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=3" style="width: 315px; height: 250px;">
    <figcaption>Name:<br>
      <span>Likes:</span></figcaption>
  </figure>
  
    <figure class="einzel"><img alt="Mitglieder" src="https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=3" style="width: 315px; height: 250px;">
    <figcaption>Name:<br>
      <span>Likes:</span></figcaption>
 
  </figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this. First create a array of objects that contains data.
Sort the array and loop over it and add to html.

```js
const imgArr = [
  { src: "https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=0", Name: "Something1", Likes: 6 },
  { src: "https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=0", Name: "Something2", Likes: 2 },
  { src: "https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=0", Name: "Something2", Likes: 3 },
  { src: "https://unsplash.it/300/225?image=0", Name: "Something2", Likes: 1 },
];

const html = imgArr.sort((a, b) => {
return a.Likes - b.Likes
}).map(imageItem => {
  return `<figure class="einzel"><img alt="Mitglieder" src=${
    imageItem.src
  } style="width: 315px; height: 250px;">
      <figcaption>Name: ${imageItem.Name}<br>
        <span>Likes: ${imageItem.Likes}</span></figcaption>
  </figure>`;
});

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="app"></div>
 <script src="src/index.js">
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great vanilla JS answer. Not saying that it should be the answer but as a comment, this already enters the territory where I would personally grab React or other UI library.